# Delay when attempting to SSH to a system

Tags: bash, ssh, openssh

I am facing a delay of about 5-6 seconds when I try to ssh from my system to a friend's system. Here is the verbose output of the command :

```
zeus@athena:~$ ssh -v ashwin@192.168.40.211
OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7, OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.40.211 [192.168.40.211] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/zeus/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/zeus/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/zeus/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host '192.168.40.211' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/zeus/.ssh/known_hosts:71
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received

<---- delay 4-5 seconds------>


debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/zeus/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /home/zeus/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/zeus/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Can someone help me figure out how i can get rid of this delay?

Comment: A common DNS issue. See http://superuser.com/questions/372238 and http://sysadvent.blogspot.nl/2010/12/day-8-everything-is-dns-problem.html

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in the comments, this could be a DNS issue. There's an article covering some steps to try and solve this here:
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/openssh-slow-at-ssh2_msg_service_accept-received/

The advice given boils down to editing `/etc/sshd_config` adding / changing `UseDNS no` and then restarting sshd. Obviously that can be tricky without access to the server!

It should also be pointed out, that setting `UseDNS` to `no` might not be the best solution in the long term. Probably better to fix the DNS issue, if there is one, on the machine in question.

Answer (score 2):

My question seems to have an answer here:

https://superuser.com/a/654153/152271

It seems that remote host tries to do a nslookup to my hostname (the connecting one). After editing /etc/hosts in the remote host adding my IP/hostname, it fixed the delay.